# plot output of loop to pdf - produces empty page(s)

Tags: r, loops, pdf, plot, save

I used pdf("file.pdf") and dev.off() several times to save plots in R, but now I encountered a very strange problem and I have no idea where it even comes from.

I have some example code for demonstration:

```
m <- matrix(rnorm(6),6,9)
data <- data.frame(m)
rownames(m)<- c("20180_T0105", "20180_T0104", "20180_T02808", "01804_T80485", "01808_T80438", "80385_T44248")
colnames(m) <- c(1:9)
K=9

pdf("OutlierScreen.pdf")
par(mfrow=c(2,round(K/2)))
for(c in 2:K) {
  print(plot(data[,1],data[,c],xlab="O-1", ylab=paste("O-",c,sep="")))
}
dev.off()
```

I did this on my Windows Computer with R Studio and it worked fine.
Then I did this on my Linux Computer with R Studio (and additionally with R run at a cluster) at work (where I discovered the problem with original data) and it happened again:

**The pdf file is generated, but empty apart from the axes! So in this example, the data points are missing.**

What could be the source of this problem?? Could it be something with a package?

Also, related but not the main problem as I just tried to somehow fix the problem with this:
I tried to plot the graphic in a list and then print it to a pdf, but the list remains empty..?:

```
plist <- list()
par(mfrow=c(2,round(K/2)))
for(c in 2:K) {
  p<- plot(data[,1],data[,c],xlab="O-1", ylab=paste("O-",c,sep=""))
  plist[[c]] <-p
}
```

Thanks for any hint, tip, suggestion!!

Added: Session Info
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-suse-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: openSUSE Leap 15.0

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=de_DE.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=de_DE.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.0 tools_3.5.0

Comment: Hi, I could not reproduce the problem (and I also run R under Linux). Can you provide the result of the instruction `sessionInfo()`?
Also, why do you add a `print()` instruction within your `for` loop? Using simply `plot` would be sufficient. This might be an explanation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I added the print, because I searched if I can find an answer to this question on the web before asking, and there some people wrote that if you use a for loop together with pdf, you need to add print (I tried it before with only plot, same problem).